# Can I make it so Future and Future Builder constantly updates the data displayed?

Tags: flutter, dart

My future function gets the data from a link. The problem is that the value from the source changes but the app just retains the old one. I know the code works because if I hot restart, I immediately get the most recent value.

These are the pieces of my code

```
class field_1 {
  String? createdAt;
  int? entryId;
  String? field1;

  field_1({this.createdAt, this.entryId, this.field1});

  field_1.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    entryId = json['entry_id'];
    field1 = json['field1'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['entry_id'] = this.entryId;
    data['field1'] = this.field1;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Here is the Future:

```
Future<String?> param() async{
    String url1 = "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1864145/fields/1/last.json";
    var response1 = await http.get(url1);

    field_1 fieldno1 = field_1.fromJson(jsonDecode(response1.body));

    String? co2 = fieldno1.field1;
    print(co2);
    return co2;
  }
```

Here is the Future builder:

```
FutureBuilder<String?>(
              future: param(),
                builder: (context, snapshot){
                  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                    var snap = snapshot.data;
                    var CO2 = int.parse('$snap');
                    print('$snap');
                    return Text('$CO2');
                  }
                  else{
                    return Text('wait');
                  }
                }
            )
```

Comment: FutureBuilder, and Futures in general, are not the right tool for this sort of task. Futures complete once and only once, and FutureBuilder reacts at most once to that single state change. You probably want to look into Streams and different resources available to create streams and react to changes in streaming data, for example  Bloc

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've been looking into Streams since yesterday but I haven't yet found anything where the value was not preset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to update the data.
I ended up using stream controller and stream builder. Thank you for the answers.

```
    StreamController<field_1> _streamController = StreamController();

  void dispose(){
    _streamController.close();
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) {
      param();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn you FutureBuilder into a StreamBuilder .

like this :

```
StreamBuilder<String?>(
              stream: Stream.fromFuture(param),
                builder: (context, snapshot){
                  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                    var snap = snapshot.data;
                    var CO2 = int.parse('$snap');
                    print('$snap');
                    return Text('$CO2');
                  }
                  else{
                    return Text('wait');
                  }
                }
            )
```

Comment: This won't help make repeated requests to the backend, or really change the behavior at all: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/Stream.fromFuture.html

Comment: I agree ! I just gave him an example , he should find the right way to implement it .

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've seen Stream and Streambuilder but I've only seen sample codes with preset values. I'll try to search for more samples.